# Android Show database entries in listview

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I have searched and cannot figure out why my code is not working correctly. I want to display a row from my database and show all the records of that row in a listview. The code works, however it only returns one listview value and not all records from the row inside the database. Here is my updated code:

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase ("Names", MODE_PRIVATE, null); 

    String query = "SELECT * from players";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    int count = c.getCount();
    c.moveToFirst();

    ListView layout=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);  

    for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++){ 


        String lister = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("names_of"));

        String[] items = {lister};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        layout.setAdapter(adapter);
    c.moveToNext();

    }

    db.close();


}
```

The array is working incorrectly, how do I get more than the first value? Thank you all in advance
 [image]

Comment: I think textview is not used anymore. then why are creating textview in loop ?

Comment: You are right! thank you for cleaning my code!

Answer (score 0):

use this one, You should be store all value in string array and move the adapter line out of loop

```
for (Integer j = 0; j < count; j++){ 
String[j] items = lister;
}

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
  layout.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
try to use this:

db = openOrCreateDatabase ("Names", MODE_PRIVATE, null); 

String query = "SELECT * from players";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
int count = 0;
String[] items=new String[c.getCount()]; 

if (c.moveToFirst()) {

  do {
            TextView txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            txt.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("names_of")));
            txt.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            txt.setTextSize(20.0f);
            txt.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            String lister = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("names_of"));
            items[count] = lister;
            count++;


     } while (c.moveToNext());

   }
  c.close();
 }
  db.close();
```

after that set adapter if `items` is not empty

```
  if(items.length>0){
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
      layout.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```